# How to build a binary tree that if inserted succefully return True in python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

I created a binary tree that has nodes of tuples. I want my insert function to insert if the tuple is not in the tree and return True if inserted. Currently, it appears to be properly inserting correctly but it's not returning the bool value correctly.

```
class D_1_tuple_tree(): #binary Tree

def __init__(self,data=None):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data

def insert(self,data): #insert Function
    if data==self.data:
        return False
    if self.data:
        if isinstance(data,tuple): #if tuple of size > 1
            tuple_lens=len(data)
            for i in range(0,tuple_lens):
                if data[i]!=self.data[i]:
                    if data[i]<self.data[i]:
                        if self.left is None:
                            self.left = D_1_tuple_tree(data)
                            return True
                        else:
                            self.left.insert(data)
                    elif data[i] > self.data[i]:
                        if self.right is None:
                            self.right = D_1_tuple_tree(data)
                            return True
                        else:
                            self.right.insert(data)


        else: #tuple of size 1
            if data!=self.data:
                if data<self.data:
                    if self.left is None:
                        self.left = D_1_tuple_tree(data)
                        return True
                    else:
                        self.left.insert(data)
                elif data > self.data:
                    if self.right is None:
                        self.right = D_1_tuple_tree(data)
                        return True
                    else:
                        self.right.insert(data)
                else:
                    return False

    else:
        self.data=data
        return True
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the result of your recursion, e.g. `return self.left.insert(data)`.

Comment: Than you! I've been struggling with this bug.